# Elevated Privileges

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, runwithelevatedprivileges, impersonation

I am writing a Webpart for an on-premise SharePoint 2013. I need to persist data to a list with elevated privileges but still need to be able to keep track who changed and added items.

When I view the version history I can only see the System Account, because of of the elevated privileges all changes are done with this account.

Is there a way where I can get a privileged web but still keep the User Information of the actual user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `Modified, Created, Author and Editor` with the actual user and time and then call `SPListItem.SystemUpdate` instead of `SPListItem.Update`. This way time stamps and actual user information will be preserved.

`SPListItem.SystemUpdate` Updates the database with changes that are made to the list item without changing the Modified or Modified By fields.